# Forgotten username, password or both

Tags: password, formatting, username, password-reminder

I am having some trouble with the wording of the following:

> Forgotten your Username or Password? Both?

[image: Example Screenshot]

Where **Username**, **Password** and **Both** are links.

Is there a need for the **Both** option or should the user simply click both the **Username** and then the **Password** links?

Alternatively keeping the **Both** option is there a nicer way to include in the main body of the question and keeping a separation of links with another word.

I have been trying to find examples of where I have seen this used in practice but my mind is drawing a blank so please references any sites that use a similar recovery statement.

Comment: First post on this site, please edit and improve :)

Comment: You could simply put one link on 'Forgotten' and send people to a form where they can enter username or email (or whatever you will actually use to recover a lost username), making it clear that you can input either one. That reduces the choices and keeps it simple. Basically you don't need that information at that early stage, it will be obvious once the user enters what he or she does remember. So don't bother the user with asking an additional time. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not set up one link that shows "Forgot username or password?" and sends an email with the username, and a link to optionally reset your password?

[image]

If I had the decision, I would set up the site to sign in with an email address and only have a "Forgot password?" link.

Comment: Just edited this answer to add the image so that the solution has a visual aspect

Comment: What website is this from?

Comment: Got it from a google image search for login forms

Comment: Automatically sending along the username with the password reset email would be a terrific way to resolve the issue, as then a user would know both pieces of information without having to go through the process twice.

The second half of your answer is an even better solution if the project is in early enough phases for it to be considered. Making the 'username' an email address eliminates having to remember an arbitrary username (especially if you need to remember your email to have a password reset anyways)